# cannot access chef server via hostname but through IP Address

Tags: chef-infra

Connecting to host 192.168.xx.xx:xxxx
ERROR: The SSL cert is signed by a trusted authority but is not valid for the given hostname
ERROR: You are attempting to connect to: '192.168.xx.xx'
ERROR: The server's certificate belongs to 'chef-server-1-b5ff9fff-fp2mg'

TO FIX THIS ERROR:

The solution for this issue depends on your networking configuration. If you
are able to connect to this server using the hostname chef-server-1-b5ff9fff-fp2mg
instead of 192.168.xx.xx, then you can resolve this issue by updating chef_server_url
in your configuration file.

If you are not able to connect to the server using the hostname chef-server-1-b5ff9fff-fp2mg
you will have to update the certificate on the server to use the correct hostname.

The problem is that i cannot access my server by hostname
What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that there is a dns resolution for your chef-server hostname.

for instance, if the chef-server hostname is chef.example.com and it is associated with the public ip address 1.2.3.4, then check the dns and make sure that this is the case. you can do so by querying the dns (see an example below on how to query the dns for cloudflare.com)

```sh
$ dig cloudflare.com +short
198.41.215.162
198.41.214.162
```

then verify the `chef_server_url` in your [`client.rb`](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb.html) holds the chef-server hostname.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have given a host name to my IP Address in my windows machine in hosts file in system32 folder and it worked.